# WIndows Authentication not working

Tags: iis-7

Newly installed IIS on a clean windows Server 2008 R2. Installed all security option. Then for the default web site authentication, enabled windows authentication and disabled all others. Then when access the default page iisstart.htm, it should give me a popup for authentication message.

but when I access the test page like: http://localhost/iisstart.htm, there is no popup. same as enabled Anonymous Authentication.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think your webservice is accessing files via your app pool identity, remove this user from the security access list on the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to "localhost", then IE will see this as part of the "Intranet Zone".  In the "Intranet Zone", IE will by default automatically send your current credentials to sites that use "Windows Authentication".

The result is that everything is probably working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you check if the app pool user can access the files of the website (NTFS security settings). See: [IIS7 Permissions Overview - ApplicationPoolIdentity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334216/iis7-permissions-overview-applicationpoolidentity)

After that (and double checking that only Windows Authentication is enabled in IIS) take into account that your **URL must not contain dots**! You can make an extra binding (see: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692(v=ws.10).aspx) that contains only letters and numbers and then add that binding to your local hosts file (open a text editor as administrator and then edit the file hosts in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc) to check.