# Asp.net Windows Authentication not working

Tags: asp.net

Confused about Windows authentication.

I tried in the below way.

1) I have created 2 pages Home.aspx and Admin.aspx

2) Created Virtual directory and placed my application in the IIS.

3) Antonymous access is false and Integrated windows security is true.

4) In the web.config file haven given this code.

```
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>


    <authorization>
----------------------      

    </authorization>
```

5) Created new user under Computer management.

trying with various roles section in  tag.

But what ever I am entering as a roles it is not asking the credentials.

seems some where near to roles section in  tag is making problem.

please help me out what was the tag need to add for windows authentication.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: do you use IE? If yes, do you have 'enable integrated windows authentication' checked in advanced settings?

Comment: @Robert: yes, it was checked only

Comment: "trying with various roles section in tag" - be more specific about what you're trying, what you're seeing, and what you're expecting to see.  If you add "allow" elements for one or more roles, you may also need to append an element `<deny users="*"/>`

Comment: @Joe: my expected out put will be it should ask the credentials of my windows login when i run the webpage. i am follwoing below article.http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98950/ASP-NET-authentication-and-authorization#Windows Authentication but iam not understanding what is this section in authorizatio tag            <allow roles="questpon-srize2\Administrator"/>

Comment: @ChaitanyaPhani - this will depend on the browser.  IE and some other recent browsers will use your current credentials without prompting if the browser is in the same domain or on the same machine as the web site.

Comment: @Joe: might be that is the possibility .                       <authorization>
<allow roles="questpon-srize2\Administrator"/>
<deny users="*"/>
</authorization> what is the <allow roles="questpon-srize2\Administrator"/> section ? could you tell me what it is for

Comment: @Joe: thanks for your suggestion, and i am able to test this for users.  <authorization>
       
          <deny users="brainstorm\abcd"/>
        </authorization> just any body could figure out what is roles for?

Comment: @ChaitanyaPhani - roles would correspond to Windows Groups in this case.

Comment: @Joe: Thank you very much, hope i am good state now.

Answer (score -1):

You must also make sure your **URL does not contain dots**!

See my answer on: [WIndows Authentication not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109739/windows-authentication-not-working)