# IIS express windows authentication not working

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I am using IIS express with windows authentication mode enabled and anonymous authentication disabled.

However, when I run the application, the IE prompts for user name and password and my windows password is not working.
How can we prevent IE from prompting for user name?

Comment: Please check my answer on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109739/windows-authentication-not-working